# How to display items from redux store in angular5 app?

Tags: angular, redux, angular-redux

I have an angular5 component that I am trying to hookup with a reduxstore, it looks like this:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NgRedux, select, DevToolsExtension } from '@angular-redux/store';
import { TodoActions } from './actions';
import { AppState, INITIAL_STATE, rootReducer } from './store';
import {Observable} from "rxjs/Observable";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  template: `    
    <input type="text" #edit />
    <button (click)="actions.add({data:edit,action:'ADD'})">add</button>
    <p>The list is:</p>
    <ul>
      <li *ngFor="let item of (items | async)">
        {{item}}
      </li>
    </ul>
  `,
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'app';
  @select() readonly items$: Observable<string[]>;

  constructor(
    ngRedux: NgRedux<AppState>,
    devTools: DevToolsExtension,
    private actions: TodoActions) {

    ngRedux.configureStore(
      rootReducer,
      INITIAL_STATE,
      null,
      devTools.isEnabled() ? [ devTools.enhancer() ] : []);
  }
}
```

The issue is that I cannot display items in the list. Here is the rootreducer:

```
import {Action} from 'redux';
import {TodoActions} from './actions';

export interface AppState {
  items: string[];
}
export const INITIAL_STATE: AppState = {items: []};

export function rootReducer(state: AppState, action: Action): AppState {
  switch (action.type) {
    case TodoActions.ADD:
      var newstate = state;
      newstate.items.push(action.data.data.value);
      return newstate;
  }
  ;

default:
  return state;
}
}
```

How can I display the items? it looks like the first item gets added to the state from the redux-console. Here is also a [githublink](https://github.com/dimitri-a/redux_angular2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This doesn't look quite right:

```ts
  var newstate = state;
  newstate.items.push(action.data.data.value);
  return newstate;
```

You're not actually creating a new array or a copy: both `newstate` and `state` are the same array, so you're probably better off returning a new array shallow-cloned:

```ts
export function rootReducer(state: AppState, action): AppState {
  switch (action.type) {
    case TodoActions.ADD:
      return {
        ...state,
        items: [
          ...state.items,
          action.data.value
        ]
      }

    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

You might notice I've pulled the type specifier off `action`. I'm not sure it makes sense to specify `Action` as the type for action, in most sample code I've seen that passed untyped so:

```ts
export function rootReducer(state: AppState, action): AppState {
```

This will avoid TS complaining about lack of `data` on type `Action`. Alternatively, you could define a custom action type for each reducer you write.

Once you get past that, I think the reason you're not seeing any items is because you name the array `items$` in the `@select` decorator. So:

```ts
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  template: `    
    <input type="text" #edit />
    <button (click)="actions.add({value:edit.value,action:'ADD'})">add</button>
    <p>The list is:</p>
    <ul>
      <li *ngFor="let item of (items$ | async)">
        {{item}}
      </li>
    </ul>
  `,
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'app';
  @select() readonly items$: Observable<string[]>;
```

works better. Note I tweaked the button definition a bit to avoid passing the entire input through, since you only need the `value`.